# What is $f_!$ in the context of commutative rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a morphism of schemes $f:X \to Y$ there is a functor $f_!:Sh(X) \to Sh(Y)$ where
$$
f_!\mathcal{F}(U) = \{ s \in \mathcal{F}(f^{-1}(U)) : f:\text{supp}(s) \to U \text{ is proper} \}
$$
How do I repackage this in the setting of commutative rings? I know that $f_*:\text{Mod}(S) \to \text{Mod}(R)$ is just composition of the $S$-action with the morphism $f:R \to S$, but I'm not sure how to interpret the support and properness in this setting.

Comment: In the affine world, proper and finite coincide.

Comment: How do I write down the support of an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answer isn't too sloppy, but I think you're mixing two different worlds here: There's the 'analytic world', where you consider *sheaves of vector spaces* over spaces like manifolds or etale sites over schemes, and there's the 'algebraic world', where you consider *coherent sheaves* over complex manifolds or schemes. The *construction* of $f_!$ as you describe it belongs to the analytic world, and - to my knowledge at least, please correct me if I'm wrong - can't be made sense of in the algebraic context (although it often makes sense to put $f_!:=f_\ast$ for coherent sheaves, see below). In any case, I think one should first be clear about what kinds of sheaves one considers.

*Edit* If you restrict to quasi-compact, separated morphisms between quasi-compact schemes (perhaps I forgot some more assumptions), one puts $f_!=f_\ast$ (which makes sense since the main point is to have a pushforward which commutes with sums, and in the context of schemes, quasi-compactness rather than properness ensures this) and shows the existence of a derived six-functor formalism as KReiser hinted at below. But still, I am not aware of a general six-functor-formalism for coherent sheaves attached to any morphism of schemes, especially none in which one puts $f_!\neq f_\ast$.

Comment: Hello Hanno, extraordinary direct image can certainly be made sense of for coherent sheaves- often one would want to take the derived version of this functor to see the full story, but one can certainly work with the underived version. See for instance https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/six+operations

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for your comment, but I am still not aware of a _general_ six functor formalism, neither of an underived proper direct image, in the context of schemes. If you restrict to quasi-compact, separated morphisms between some suitable schemes, then you put $f_!=f_\ast$ and prove on the triangulated level that there's an adjoint, but what would be $f_!$ in general, let alone underived?

Comment: My apologies, I was sloppy and largely incorrect. A much better thing to say would be what you've written in your 2nd paragraph. I think I pieced together two misremembered notions to make a third worse one.

Comment: @KReiser No worries, might as well have been me mixing up things.

Comment: @user251222: Do you have questions?